# Action filter on OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I have extended `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` with `ApplicationOAuthProvider`, and I'd like to know if there's a way to apply an action filter to it. Specifically, is there a way to apply an action filter attribute to `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.GrantResourceOwnerCredentials()`?

This obviously doesn't work:

```cs
[LogRequestResponse]
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
```

Alternatively, is there a way to make the request for a token pass through `AccountController` at some point?

Maybe make a change here?

```cs
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions {
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/Account/ExternalLogin"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
    AllowInsecureHttp = true // for development purposes
};
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. ActionFilters are an MVC/WebAPI concept - the OAuth2 middleware intercepts the request before even reaching the upper level frameworks.